# Msmq over cluster, how to know if a service is under cluster?

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq, cluster-computing

We have developed our product with the ability for scaling and failover.
The Servers communicates with each other with `wcf` over `msmq` for durability, we had our trouble the configure the use of a window service under a cluster to use the clustered msmq.
The answer was to configure the `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` in the service start up as following `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_,"Cluster");` and after that the wcf over clustered msmq is working, but the problem is to know when the service is under cluster and when he is not.
is there any way to know that ?

**UPDATE**

After consulting with Microsoft we have reached the conclusion that the architecture of the cluster using MSMQ was wrong, MSMQ is a service and not a server therefor each server that is the master of the queue needs to configured with the msmq as a dependency in its own group. the msmq will take care of messages between the nodes and server client.

Answer (score 1):

We are using WCF (netMsmqBinding) in combination with clustered MSMQ. 
When your MSMQ service is added in the Failover cluster manager (2008) or cluster admin (2003)

you have a networkname let's say "MyNetworkName" that has an IP. 
The MSMQ is accessibel on that networkname - so your queue definition in your config should start with the MyNetworkName\private... or If your WCF service is also running as Windows service in your cluster you can choose for the resource option "Use network name for comutername" and you can use ".\private...." in your config - "remark: than the Windows service should run in the same resource group as MSMQ".

**Edit: so if I understand your question well, when you are the checkbox "use networkname .... " on your clustered service the same code will use the clustered msmsq, but if you are not running on a cluster or not in a resource group it will use the local msmq**

Make sure your MSMQ is installed in directory service integration mode.

To organize the clustered MSMQ you can use the mmcv.exe tool from microsoft (the regular mmc.exe tool is not sufficient).

You can read about mmcv.exe here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898701